# C++ - Using code blocks, class can't be accessed

Tags: c++

The code does not run. I am using CodeBlocks.

I just learned how to create classes and access them,
I am new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Bclass(){
    public:
        void print(){
            cout << "h" << endl;
        }
 };

int main(){
    Bclass c;
    c.print();
    return 0;
}


I expected the screen to print "h" but it didn't work.

Error results:

   /Users/jo/Desktop/classes/main.cpp|4|error: expected unqualified-id|

   /Users/jo/Desktop/classes/main.cpp|12|error: variable has incomplete type 'Bclass'|

   /Users/jo/Desktop/classes/main.cpp|4|note: forward declaration of 'Bclass'|

   ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Look at the line causing the error. Compare that to the correct syntax of a class definition.

Comment: Sometimes you can learn a lot from comparing your code to the examples in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Remove () from the front of class BClass.